# Can't get open ports for a server (possibly modem related)

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, nat, hosting

I am attempting to host an [Unturned](http://store.steampowered.com/app/304930/) server. It is running from a dedicated box on my local network. I have correctly port forwarded on my Netgear router. My modem (Thompson ST5) also has an option for port forwarding. The setting on the modem port forward is the IP for the router instead of the server IP; I have tried with this IP too, but no luck.

If I go to any port checkers online or offline (the ones you install) every port i check times out. even with the server running i can only see the ports being used when i put netstat -ab into cmd. it comes up as

[UDP] 0.0.0.0:27016 (unturned.exe)

27016 is the port i wish to use. and the forwarded ports are 27015-27018.

even with the server running (and thus the port is being 'used', connection from beyond the LAN remains impossible)

edit:

Even when DMZ is on, nothing comes through, and the server is only accessible over LAN.

Also, unturned uses the port defined plus 1, so if the starting port is 27015, the server will use 27016

Comment: might be ISP related Its worth checking whether your isp uses CGN or some other thing like that.

Comment: Look for the “external” IP addresses of both your router and your modem. Include them in your question. Also, how is the router WAN set up? Simply DHCP?

Comment: thanks Journeyman Geek, it seems that this is the issue. But how can i disable or stop using this CGN or LSN????

Comment: @JustBlu You can't. Talk to your ISP.

Answer (score 0):

People host their servers by using dedicated public servers that can be found in the server browser. It is very easy to host in 2.0 flawlessly but hosting in 3.0 is little much harder. I enabled DMZ in my router to get work from it.

As you said, forwarded ports are 27015-27018. But according to me, We can’t just open the port 27015 or 27016 but we need 27015-27018 ports open and DMZ works. After forwarding ports 27015-27017, DMZ will be enabled and it’ll open every port on the router. Keep in mind that the target of DMZ is your IP address.

Comment: That won't fix a CGN issue which it appears is the OP's problem.